# Typescript compiler throwing an error when adding baseurl configuration option

Tags: reactjs, typescript, path

Im trying to enable absolute imports on my react project which just compiles with typescript.
I have been told that I should add the baseUrl config option which tells the compiler where to look. But when I compile my code, I get the following error:

```js
//Broken
import { useMeQuery } from 'generated/graphql';

//Works
import { useMeQuery } from '../../generated/graphql';
```

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Pages/HomePage.tsx
Module not found: Your application tried to access generated, but it isn't declared in your dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.
```

If I add paths to my tsconfig, I then get the following error.

```
/Users/pkwadsy/src/projects/belemon/web/.yarn/$$virtual/react-scripts-virtual-f1dd360a52/0/cache/react-scripts-npm-4.0.0-675c13e360-508ceb13ad.zip/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239

      appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = value;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'paths' of object '#<Object>'
    at verifyTypeScriptSetup (/Users/pkwadsy/src/projects/belemon/web/.yarn/$$virtual/react-scripts-virtual-f1dd360a52/0/cache/react-scripts-npm-4.0.0-675c13e360-508ceb13ad.zip/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pkwadsy/src/projects/belemon/web/.yarn/$$virtual/react-scripts-virtual-f1dd360a52/0/cache/react-scripts-npm-4.0.0-675c13e360-508ceb13ad.zip/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:31:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.external_module_.Module._load (/Users/pkwadsy/src/projects/belemon/web/.pnp.js:26999:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

None of this makes any sense to me, any help would be appreciated :)

Here is my config file.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src": ["./src"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules",
        "options": {
          "classnameTransform": "camelCase"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: any update/solution? 

Answer (score 0):

delete your tsconfig.json and do npm start again